# How to make a ggplot graph showing a factor in x axis and continuous variables in y axis

Tags: r

Hi dear I have a little problem with a graphic in ggplot, I want to design a graphic that shows in x axis a varible that is a factor and in y axis the values of two continuous variables, to see the difference between first continuous and second variable related to the factor variable. The data frame is similar to this:

```
Group  Var1 Var2
1       10   20
2       15   30
3       5    10
4       20   15
5       5    5
```

My objective is to see the difference between var1 and var to in each member of factor. It is possible to make this in ggplot. Thanks a lot of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usualy, you should reshape your data in the long format to compare between variable. For example  using `melt` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat,id.vars='Group')
```

Then , for example, I am plotting here a `geom_bar` to compare between levels. Of course you can choose another geom.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat.m)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=Group,y=value,fill=variable),
               stat='identity',position='dodge')
```

[image]